# Do multiple node.js "requires" impact production run time?

Tags: node.js

We are integrating Amazon's node.js SDK into our project and while I do not think it matters due to require's cache and the fact that everything is compiled, I could not find a site that definitively states that multiple requires will not affect performance in run time.

Obviously it depends on what files you are requiring, the contents of those files, and whether or not they could block the event loop or have other code inside of them to slow performance.

I prefer to structure code based on functionality rather than just having a 10000+ line file that does not really relate to the task at hand. I just want to make sure I'm not shooting myself in the foot by break out functionality into separate modules and then requiring on an as needed basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `require()` is a synchronous operation so it should ONLY be used during server initialization, never during an actual request.  Therefore, the performance of `require()` should only affect your server startup time, not your request handling time.

Second, `require()` does have a cache behind it.  It matches the fully resolved path of the module you are attempting to load.  So, if you call `require(somePath)` and a module at that same path has previously been loaded, then the module handle is just immediately returned from the cache.  No module is loaded from disk a second time.  The module code is not executed a second time.

> Obviously it depends on what files you are requiring, the contents of those files, and whether or not they could block the event loop or have other code inside of them to slow performance.

If you are requiring a module for the first time, it WILL block the event loop while loading that module because `require()` uses blocking, synchronous I/O when the module is not yet cached.  That's why you should be doing this at server initialization time, not during a request handler.

> I prefer to structure code based on functionality rather than just having a 10000+ line file that does not really relate to the task at hand. I just want to make sure I'm not shooting myself in the foot by break out functionality into separate modules and then requiring on an as needed basis.

Breaking code into logical modules is good for ease of maintenance, ease of testing and ease of reuse, so it's definitely a good thing.

I have seen people go too far where there are so many modules each with only a few lines of code in them that it backfires and makes the project unwieldly to work on, find things in, design test suites for, etc...  So, there is a balance.

Comment: Thanks!. That is what I figured and I agree 100% in terms of not having so many separate files with little to no actual code and we will limit to server initialization rather than inside of http.createServer.